# IBOutlet will not instantiate

Tags: properties, uitextview, iboutlet, nul

Alright,

I have a weird one here. I have created a VERY simple `UIViewController` that has 1 big `UITextView` on it.

In my `.h` file I declare a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *displayTextView;
```

and then synthesize it like this:

```
@synthesize displayTextView;
```

Then I go to load it using:

```
ExampleViewController *eVC = [[ExampleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExampleView" bundle:nil];
[eVC.displayTextView setText:@"This is the string I want to show!!!"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:eVC animated:YES];
```

For some stupid reason the text view is never instantiated and when I use breakpoints to go through it is NULL. I am using Xcode 4 with ARC, can ANYONE please explain why this extremely simple code that would have worked in Xcode 3 refuses to in Xcode 4?

Before you ask, YES I have triple checked my IB connection from the outlet to the text view.

GRRR, this is so frustrating! Please help!